# Why `querySelectorAll` does not work as intended

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make all `li` elements turn to `"Hello"` when I hit the `Test Button` but `querySelectorAll` doesn't do anything, but if I replace with `querySelector` it works fine for just one element. What am I missing here?

```js
function test() {
    var foundDiv = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    foundDiv.innerText = "Hello";
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <section id="container">
        <ul>
            <li class="first">one</li>
            <li class="second">two</li>
            <li class="third">three</li>
        </ul>
        <ol>
            <li class="first">one</li>
            <li class="second">two</li>
            <li class="third">three</li>
        </ol>
    </section>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>

    <button onclick="test()"> Test </button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), it returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not a single item. From the docs on [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList): `Although NodeList is not an Array, it is possible to iterate over it with forEach().` So, you need to iterate over the results of the query and update each item in the list.

```js
function test() {
    var foundDivs = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    foundDivs.forEach(div => {
      div.innerText = "Hello";
    });
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <section id="container">
        <ul>
            <li class="first">one</li>
            <li class="second">two</li>
            <li class="third">three</li>
        </ul>
        <ol>
            <li class="first">one</li>
            <li class="second">two</li>
            <li class="third">three</li>
        </ol>
    </section>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>

    <button onclick="test()"> Test </button>
</body>
```